# Libreria de vue-good-table

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs, vue.js, lista

Estoy usando la libreria de vue-good-table en nuxt 2, lo que intento hacer es desde un botón externo habilitar una busqueda en la tabla para cierta fila en este caso solo quiero que se manipule la barra de dezplazamiento de la tabla para mostrar fila requerida, como podria hacerlo recomendación

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y que fue lo que intentaste???